# Get alias for SelectSum

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I am trying to replicate this SQL query in NHibernate:

```
SELECT player.NAME, 
       Sum(achievement.value) AS 'Goals Scored' 
FROM   player 
       JOIN playerperformance 
         ON playerperformance.player_id = player.id 
       JOIN achievement 
         ON achievement.playerperformance_id = playerperformance.id 
WHERE  achievement.descriptor = 'Goals Scored' 
GROUP  BY player.NAME, 
          player.id 
ORDER  BY 'Goals Scored' DESC
```

Here's my NHibernate LINQ query:

```
_dataAccessor.QueryOver<Player>()
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<PlayerPerformance>(player => player.Performances)
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<Achievement>(perf => perf.Achievements, () => achievementAlias)
    .Where(a => a.Descriptor == "Goals Scored")
    .SelectList(list => list.SelectGroup(player => player.Id).SelectSum(() => achievementAlias.Value))
    .OrderBy(a => a.Value).Desc
    .List()
    ;
```

This is almost right. But the OrderBy is going wrong. I don't know what to put in the OrderBy lambda that would make it order on the alias for the `SelectSum(...)` part. There is an alias in the generated SQL:

```
SELECT this_.id                AS y0_, 
       Sum(achievemen2_.value) AS y1_ 
FROM   [player] this_ 
       INNER JOIN [playerperformance] playerperf1_ 
               ON this_.id = playerperf1_.player_id 
       INNER JOIN [achievement] achievemen2_ 
               ON playerperf1_.id = achievemen2_.playerperformance_id 
WHERE  achievemen2_.descriptor = @p0 
GROUP  BY this_.id 
ORDER  BY achievemen2_.value DESC
```

So all I need to do is persuade NHibernate to do `ORDER BY y1_` instead of `ORDER BY achievemen2_.Value`. But I can't figure out how to get the alias for the sum.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. `SelectSum(...)` has a `WithAlias` method, so I could point to an integer alias representing the sum. Then I just had to use `OrderByAlias(...)` instead of `OrderBy(...)`:

```
int sumAlias = 0;

_dataAccessor.QueryOver<Player>()
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<PlayerPerformance>(player => player.Performances)
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<Achievement>(perf => perf.Achievements, () => achievementAlias)
    .Where(a => a.Descriptor == "Goals Scored")
    .SelectList(list => list.SelectGroup(player => player.Id).SelectSum(() => achievementAlias.Value).WithAlias(() => sumAlias)
    .OrderByAlias(() => sumAlias).Desc
    .List<object[]>()
    ;
```